# Why do custom MIME types keep disappearing?

Tags: iis, iis-10

I have a vanilla Server2019 IIS setup, and I need a few custom MIME types.  Adding them in the IIS Manager console is simple enough, but every few days I discover that they have disappeared and I have to add them again.  I've gone through this cycle several times.

What can be causing them to disappear?   I've read that an IISRESET can do this, but I'm not (that I know of) doing that.

Thanks.

Comment: "Adding them in the IIS Manager console is simple enough" is a red flag. It is not that simple, so after making the change in IIS Manager, you must learn where the setting is saved, in `applicationHost.config` or in a `web.config` file. Only then when the setting becomes missing next time, you know which file to look after.

Comment: you can try to put the custom mime type code in applicationhost.config file which is located at: Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config. you can set code like: `<staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".xaml" mimeType="application/xaml+xml" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".xap" mimeType="application/x-silverlight-app" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".xbap" mimeType="application/x-ms-xbap" />
     </staticContent>` and restart iis server.

Comment: I've seen other posts about updating the files, and I can do that.  However, what is the point of having the GUI interface that makes it look like adding MIME types is simple?  Using the GUI is for MIME types is recommended in many place including MS, and it works for me (for a while).  The fact that it goes away on it's own tells me that something is wrong.

Comment: you could try to use the windows auditing feature and check how these changes happen in your site. please refer this post [link](https://forums.iis.net/post/2157904.aspx) steps.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  This server has a couple websites.  The `<sitefiles>/web.config` file was getting deleted by the user in charge of placing files in the directory, and I didn't realize that a) they were doing that, and b) the web.config file is where the custom MIME types were stored.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. This was my issue as well. Please accept your answer to resolve it.